# ASP .NET MVC OutputCache wrong location

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, outputcache

I have little problem with caching my views. The location header isn't correct when I lost my ticket and get logged out, and trying to get directly into url I was before.

*Example*: I'm inside /Admin/Categories, then I'm getting logged out due to being afk too long, so I'm being redirected to /Admin/Login. After log in I'm trying to go to /Admin/Categories and cache is sending me into /Admin/Login instead of /Admin/Categories.

My code:

```
    LOGIN CONTROLLER
    [OutputCache(CacheProfile = "OneDayCache", VaryByParam = "None", VaryByCustom = "url")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    CATEGORIES CONTROLLER
    [OutputCache(CacheProfile = "OneDayCache", VaryByParam = "None", VaryByCustom = "url")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (validations.ValidateTicket())
        {
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
        }
    }
```

validations.ValidateTicket() is returning true or false and it's working good - it's not the problem.

```
    GLOBAL.ASAX.CS
    public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string arg)
    {
        if (arg == "url")
        {
            return context.Request.RawUrl;
        }
        return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, arg);
    }
```

Web.config part inside :

```
<caching>
  <outputCache enableOutputCache="true" omitVaryStar="true"></outputCache>
  <outputCacheSettings>
    <outputCacheProfiles>
      <add name="OneDayCache" duration="86400" location="Client" />
    </outputCacheProfiles>
  </outputCacheSettings>
</caching>
```

Cache - Login (/Admin/Login)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, max-age=86400
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Expires: Fri, 10 Feb 2017 20:35:45 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 09 Feb 2017 20:35:45 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?TTpcUHJvamVrdHlcQU1CSVQtQ01TLU1WQ1xBTUJJVCBDTVMgTVZDXEFkbWluXExvZ2lu?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 09 Feb 2017 20:35:45 GMT
Content-Length: 1113
```

Cache - Categories (/Admin/Categories) - look at location header which is wrong...

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private, max-age=86400
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Fri, 10 Feb 2017 20:35:39 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 09 Feb 2017 20:35:39 GMT
Location: /Admin/Login
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?TTpcUHJvamVrdHlcQU1CSVQtQ01TLU1WQ1xBTUJJVCBDTVMgTVZDXEFkbWluXENhdGVnb3JpZXM=?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 09 Feb 2017 20:35:39 GMT
Content-Length: 439
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the problem was that OutputCache location with VaryByCustom used as parameter needs to be set to Server or any other using Server location too.

For example:

Usage in controller:

```
[OutputCache(CacheProfile = "ControllerIndexCache")]
```

Web.config:

```
<caching>
  <outputCache enableOutputCache="true" omitVaryStar="true"></outputCache>
  <outputCacheSettings>
    <outputCacheProfiles>
      <add name="ControllerIndexCache" duration="10" location="Server" varyByCustom="Url" varyByParam="None" />
    </outputCacheProfiles>
  </outputCacheSettings>
</caching>
```

Global.asax.cs:

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string arg)
    {
        if (arg == "Url")
        {
            return context.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
        }
        return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, arg);
    }
```

This solution is working just fine.